# Why is axios behaving diferently in Jest than natively?

Tags: javascript, axios, jestjs

I'm doing some black box testing of an running app and Jest is behaving expectantly.

const axios = require('axios')

```
describe('the http service endpoints',() => {
  test('that the http service is accepting requests to the endpoint /health', () =>
    axios
      .get('http://0.0.0.0:3265/health')
      .then(res => {
        expect(res.status).toEqual(200)
      }))
})
```

I'm getting this error

> console.error
> Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden

But when I run this same test using nodes native assertion and without being in Jest, axios behaves as I would expect and does not error.

Comment: Jest uses jsdom as default environment on tests (ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string). So it tries to send requests as it's like on the browser. If you change this configuration as node, I think your problem will be resolved. Simply put `--env=node` to the npm script or change jest config.

Comment: Correct! Thank you so much! It worked, put it as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jest uses jsdom as default environment on tests

(ref: [jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string](http://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string)).

So it tries to send requests as it's like on the browser. If you change this configuration as node, I think your problem will be resolved.

Simply put --env=node to the npm script or change jest config